# PHP Subtracting two number gives wrong values

Tags: php

My PHP code:

```
$a = 25,787;
$b = 5,661;
$c = $b - $a;
```

Expect answer is -20126. 
Gives output: 0,20,126.

Comment: This looks like the output would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

When I execute your code I'll get an syntax error, because of the comma. So I've changed it a bit. This will result in the float that you see on your screen

```
<?php
$a = 25.787;
$b = 5.661;
$c = $b - $a;

echo $c;
?>
```

Please note that this will generate a float. But it looks like that you want to works with thousands. That will work when you remove the comma/dot

```
<?php
//Enter your code here, enjoy!
$a = 25787;
$b = 5661;
$c = $b - $a;

echo $c;
?>
```